# Unbind Kendo UI Grid Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo ui grid in razor, in the declaration of the grid I have this sentence:

```
.Events(ev => ev.Change("rowClick"))
```

This `rowClick` event is executing when I click on a row.

Ones the user do the first click, I activate a button and I don't need the event anymore.

How can unbind the rowClick method associated with the Change event in javascript?

My grid object:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/603/

```
function onChangeSelection() {
   alert('oh my god !');
    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").unbind('change');    
}
```

*It's what you want...*